# GetURLsource method gives in some cases erros java

Tags: java, web, web-crawler

I have developed this piece of code to get the url source code of a web page. Yet this method gives sometimes fails, and it is unable to 'grab' the source code of a page.

```
 private static String[] getUrlSource(String url) throws IOException {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    URL site = new URL(url);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                site.openStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        myList.add(inputLine);
    in.close();

    String[] arr = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: "Fails" in what way? What is the exception/stacktrace?

Comment: Instead of giving me the source code of the page my string arrays becomes filled with things as  `HŒ‘âc’ŸÆtÒ5Îy“06ûóˆÈM>u?˜ÌbÍº?Ü’ÄÝ«»óä¤Ù2ë²äu ` and `"SâÀ².ÞjHÇqtlYóùÜœ×MÆGVÿÆÇ“ aŒ bú±¯?üñ '×P€Ã‘£Eq²B°/ß'$ÆHâ1È_§tæhg,ŒIýED4ä%ß-&±BÝEÞsAbçòöÚh·›£ª!ëQ\W@yŠGy|ÀF(Äâh3JæãqîØœúñØñÉŒzÄP_*ˆ† ÂÃqª4Át2?d âuÄYDx¼p46:Žiä¹¸œ°åñÈ@çõm„QßèO}ö?f?lÁ0åA>gºDezlb5" "v½Ù¬YÛ±ÐIQ)ž54¢àL>·:0ï£ÑË§ÚhÛ?£v£ÕØN\…¸R¯[Å•ø·ÃùDxœFÒÏ¶B¯ë ?F˜Ç@(Œ™¨ ?Oáˆ 3,°Pj`AÐ˜“ácÓPŒùüJs †ÒŠ=e¯“Ô¯VÑù4" ` or `<html lang="pt">`